# Logout reverse url doesn't work with next page

Tags: python, django

In my view, I'm checking if the user who owns a specific email address is the authenticated user. If not, I want to redirect to logout and then to login with the same URL. Here is my view:

```
class VerifyUserEmailAddressView(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleObjectMixin, generic.View):
    model = UserEmailAddress
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:edit_profile_emails')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email_address = self.get_object()
        if (not (email_address.user == self.request.user)):
            return redirect(to='accounts:logout', **{'next_page': self.request.get_full_path()}) # This is the line that causes the exception.
        assert (email_address.user == self.request.user)
        ...
```

This is my logout view:

```
class LogoutView(django_auth_views.LogoutView):
    template_name = 'accounts/logged_out.html'
```

But the problem is, I get an exception:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'logout' with keyword arguments '{'next_page': '/edit-profile/emails/95209103364882328130/verify/64435189922652686051/'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['logout\\/$']
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(route='login/', view=views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path(route='logout/', view=views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    path(route='edit-profile/emails/', view=views.EditProfileEmailsView.as_view(), name='edit_profile_emails'),
    path(route='edit-profile/emails/<digits:pk>/verify/<str:token>/', view=views.VerifyUserEmailAddressView.as_view(), name='verify_email'),
]
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show your url config?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the **`next_page`** is the *URL query-parameter* rather than *URL-argument*

If so, you must generate a URL something like,

```
/account/logout/?next=/foo/bar/somewhere/
```

to do so, replace your redirect statement as,

```
from django.urls import reverse

return redirect('{}?next={}'.format(reverse('accounts:logout'), self.request.get_full_path()))
```